# Solution to $\sqrt{\sqrt{x + 5} + 5} = x$

Tags: polynomials, roots

There are natural numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$ such that the solution to the equation
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{\sqrt{x + 5} + 5} = x
\end{equation*}
is $\displaystyle{\frac{a + \sqrt{b}}{c}}$. Evaluate $a + b + c$.

I am not sure where I saw this problem. My guess is that it was from a high school math competition. The solution to the equation is $\frac{1 + \sqrt{21}}{2}$. This suggests use of the quadratic formula.

The solution set to the given equation is a subset of the solution set to
\begin{equation*}
x^{2} - 5 = \sqrt{x + 5} ,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
x^{4} - 10x^{2} + 25 = x + 5
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
x^{4} - 10x^{2} - x + 20 = 0 .
\end{equation*}
Using the quartic equation (or Wolfram), the solutions to this equation are computed to be
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{21}}{2} , \qquad  \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{17}}{2} .
\end{equation*}

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $x = \sqrt{x+5}$ then $x = \sqrt{\sqrt{x+5}+5}$.

So, try solving $x = \sqrt{x+5}$. This is a quadratic.

Comment: An elegant algebraic explanation!

Comment: Did the solution $(1/2)\sqrt{1+21}$ prompt you to look for the solution to a simpler algebraic expression?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire: No, I let $f(x) = \sqrt{x+5}$ and stated looking for fixed points $x=f(f(x))$ and then thought why not look for a fixed point $x=f(x)$ first.

Answer (score 3):

use the following way 
$$x=\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5 + x} }$$
$$x=\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5 + \sqrt{5+\sqrt{5 + \sqrt{5+\sqrt{5 + ....} }} }} }  $$
or
$$x=\sqrt{5+x }$$
$$x^2-x-5=0$$
$$x=\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{21}}{2}$$
now use long division to get the other roots and then check which which one satisfies the original equation

Comment: My guess is that this was the intended solution.

Comment: What you are really describing is a sequence of real numbers.

Comment: For a proper solution, you would have to say that this sequence is increasing and bounded.

Comment: I guess that for a high school competition, these details would be assumed.

Answer (score 0):

- You can get the four apparent solutions from $x^{4} - 10x^{2} - x + 20 = (x^2 - x - 5) (x^2 + x - 4)$ and then solving two quadratic equations
- Squaring can produce spurious results:

  - for example if $x=\frac{-1 - \sqrt{17}}{2}$ then $\sqrt{\sqrt{x + 5} + 5} = -x$ rather than $+x$
  - but you lost that distinction when you went to ${\sqrt{x + 5} + 5} = x^2$
  - similarly $x=\frac{-1 + \sqrt{17}}{2}$ or $x=\frac{1 - \sqrt{21}}{2}$ then $\sqrt{x+5} = -(x^2-5)$ rather than $+(x^2-5)$ but you lost that distinction with the second squaring

When you use transformations which are not $1-1$ then you should check any apparent answers in the original question to see whether they are spurious or not

Comment: How do you know this quartic equation factors into two quadratic polynomials?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire - (a) empirically it can be factorised (I did) and (b) your stated solutions to the quartic imply that it should be possible to factorise it

Comment: Is this what you're saying? Based on the solution that I gave in the post, you tried to find some "nice" factorization into two quadratic polynomials, and you found it with coefficients of $\pm1$, $4$, and $5$.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire - Indeed the solutions in your post implied there would be a nice factorisation of the quartic but it would always be worth looking anyway.